# How to get the version of Vmware VSpere with the Rest API?

Tags: rest, api, vmware, vsphere

I'm using the REST Api to control vSphere vCenter Server 6.5 and 6.7.
In order to distinguish the two, I found `/rest/appliance/system/version` that is working on 6.5 (in fact GET returns correctly 6.5.xx).

The same path is not working on 6.7 (not found).
Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It's operational on my system: (pulled from API Explorer)

**Request URL**

```
https://vcenter.fqdn/rest/appliance/system/version
```

**Response Body**

```
{
  "value": {
    "install_time": "2018-09-03T14:28:52 UTC",
    "summary": "Update for VMware vCenter Server Appliance 6.7.0",
    "product": "VMware vCenter Server Appliance",
    "build": "10244745",
    "releasedate": "October 16, 2018",
    "type": "vCenter Server with an embedded Platform Services Controller",
    "version": "6.7.0.20000"
  }
```

}

It's also still available in the API doc: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/423e512d-dda1-496f-9de3-851c28ca0814/0e3f6e0d-8d05-4f0c-887b-3d75d981bae5/VMware-vSphere-Automation-SDK-REST-6.7.0/docs/apidocs/operations/com/vmware/appliance/system/version.get-operation.html

Comment: Thanks Kyle. It stays a mistery then.

Comment: I'll try first to update to version U1. Keep you informed. Thanks for your support

Comment: Hi Kyle. Just to keep you informed: the page is not found (err 404) on vCenter Server 6.7 (even the last U1b) package installed on Windows. On the contrary, the appliance (same version) is replying correctly. {... "build": "11726888",
    "version": "6.7.0.21000" ...  }. Thanks

Comment: Does vSphere Client version 6.7.0.20000 has an API to update the content library session properties? Couldn't find the update session API in the above link shared.